# Upload Image and PDF in rest API using node js with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, rest

I have try to insert some data into mongodb database using node js REST API but I got an error **Unexpected field** Im new to node please help me. **whitePaper** is my **pdf** file If I upload data like title, description and image only it gives the Correct answer with status code 201 but I try to upload all data and pdf but it gives the error

model code:

```
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    imgURL: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   whitePaperLink: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
                
   },
```

app.js file

```
app.use('/whitePaper', express.static('whitePaper'));
```

router file

```
const whitePaperLink = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: './whitePaper/',
 filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      return cb(null, `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`);
 }
});
const whitePaperFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
 if (file.mimetype === 'application/pdf') {
      cb(null, true)
 } else {
      cb(null, false)
 }
};
const whitePaperUpload = multer({
 storage: whitePaperLink,
 limits: {
      fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
 },
 fileFilter: whitePaperFilter
 });

router.post('/', checkAuth, imageUpload.single('imgURL'), whitePaperUpload.single('whitePaperLink'), 
PostController.create_Post)
```

controller file

```
exports.create_Post = async (req, res) => {
 const post = new Post({
      title: req.body.title,
      category: req.body.category,
      description: req.body.description,
      imgURL: req.file.path,
      whitePaperLink: req.file.path,
      publishDate: req.body.publishDate,
 });

 try {
      const addPost = await post.save()
      res.status(201).json({
           message: 'Post Added Succesfully.'
      })
 } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
           message: error
      })

 }
}
```

Comment: You've shared the code but please mention what is the error you are facing.

Comment: @Abhishek I have got error is Unexpected field for whitePaperLink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll use `upload.single` for each field it'll give error `Unexpected Field`.

Multer takes all files at once for execution, and in your case you've 2 different files and it'll take both files to `upload.single`.

So, instead of `upload.single` use `upload.fields`.

In your `route.js`, do it like this:

```
const destination = (req, file, cb) => {
     switch (file.mimetype) {
          case 'image/jpeg':
               cb(null, './images/');
               break;
          case 'image/png':
               cb(null, './images/');
               break;
          case 'application/pdf':
               cb(null, './whitePaper/');
               break;
          default:
               cb('invalid file');
               break;
     }
}

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
     destination: destination,
     filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          return cb(null, `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`);
     }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
     if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'application/pdf') {
          cb(null, true)
     } else {
          cb(null, false)
     }
};

const upload = multer({
     storage: storage,
     limits: {
          fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
     },
     fileFilter: fileFilter
});

// add post
router.post('/', upload.fields([{ name: 'imgURL', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'whitePaperLink', maxCount: 1 }]), PostController.create_Post)
```

**Edit:**

You can also do it like this:

```
const uploadPostData = (req, res, next) => {
     upload.fields([{ name: 'imgURL', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'whitePaperLink', maxCount: 1 }])(req, res, (err) => {
          console.log(req.files);
          req.body.imgURL = req.files.imgURL[0].path.replace('/\\/g','/');
          req.body.whitePaperLink = req.files.whitePaperLink[0].path.replace('/\\/g','/');
          next()
     })
}

// add post
router.post('/', uploadPostData, PostController.create_Post)
```

Comment: Sir I have try this but controller gives the error is UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

For these two lines

          imgURL: req.file.path,
          whitePaperLink: req.file.path,

the image and pdf are saved to folder not database but it gives the path error

Comment: Have you checked in `req.files`?

Comment: Sir 


When I check req.files console gives following result
[Object: null prototype] { imgURL: [ { fieldname: 'imgURL' } ] }
[Object: null prototype] {
  imgURL: [ { fieldname: 'imgURL' } ],
  whitePaperLink: [ { fieldname: 'whitePaperLink' } ]
}

When I check file console gives following result
{
  fieldname: 'imgURL',        
  originalname: 'youtube.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png'       
}
{
  fieldname: 'whitePaperLink',  
  originalname: 'ReactTask.pdf',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/pdf'   
}

Comment: I have try this updated code but it gives the error is req.files.imgURL[0].path.replaceAll is not a function , I have try replace function insted of replaceAll but it gives the same error is like UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Comment: Can you send the response of req.files?

Comment: the req.files response is 
[Object: null prototype] {
  imgURL: [
    {
      fieldname: 'imgURL',
      originalname: 'youtube.png',
      encoding: '7bit',
      mimetype: 'image/png',
      destination: './images/',
      filename: 'imgURL_1622826527647.png',        
      path: 'images\\imgURL_1622826527647.png',    
      size: 17081
    }
  ],

Comment: whitePaperLink: [
    {
      fieldname: 'whitePaperLink',
      originalname: 'ReactTask.pdf',
      encoding: '7bit',
      mimetype: 'application/pdf',
      destination: './whitePaper/',
      filename: 'whitePaperLink_1622826527649.pdf',
      path: 'whitePaper\\whitePaperLink_1622826527649.pdf',
      size: 113101
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233335/discussion-between-ravindra-s-patil-and-abhishek-pankar).